# jsp how to escape double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
   <center>
    <span class="ReportSubsectionTitle">Report Type</span>
                                    <br />
        <html:radio  styleId="summary" property="reportOutputStyleID" onclick="doDetail();" value="2" />Pending Funding
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <html:radio  styleId="detail" property="reportOutputStyleID" onclick="doSummary();" value="1" />Previously Funded
</center>
```

So, on loading, I want the default option 2 to be selected.

```
 <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" onload="window.moveTo(0,0);
                                                       window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
                                                       window.focus();
                                                       insertOption('number');
                                                       document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID.value="2";
                                                       doDetail();">
```

I tired \" and even &quot, but it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Which double quote do you want to escape?

Comment: The one for document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID.value="2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the easiest, simplest solution and cleanest solution:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" onload="initializePage()">

<script>
    function initializePage() {
        window.moveTo(0,0);
        window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight);
        window.focus();
        insertOption('number');
        document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID.value="2";
        doDetail();
    }
</script>
```

And this function could even be stored in an external JS file, to avoid reloading each time the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use simple quote?

```
document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID.value='2';
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as nesting quotes goes you can use singles, the same as you already used for `insertOption('number')`:

```
document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID.value='2';
```

You said in a comment on another answer that that didn't work, but that must be because of some other error, not because of the quotes. I think it is because that syntax doesn't work to select a radio button. Try instead setting the checked property of the first one:

```
document.achReportCriteria.reportOutputStyleID[0].checked = true;
```

Or, better, rather than using JS just include the checked attribute directly in the markup:

```
<html:radio  styleId="summary" property="reportOutputStyleID"
 onclick="doDetail();" value="2" checked="checked" />
```